# Suggestions on interface design

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to design a kind of templating system for text: the user enters a piece of text and types some special markers like (**) inside the text that tell the software that the text (**) will need to be changed to some other content.

What I would like to do, is displaying the user the list of fields that need to be changes so that the user can insert the proper data.

I was thinking about doing that displaying all the text (in a text box) and substitute the (**) chars with a textbox so that the user can enter the text. Is there a way to do that? What do you think of this approach? Do you have better ideas? The point is that I would like to show the user the context in which the substitution takes place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not scan the text and generate textboxes on the fly?

Your code would display the templated text, scan it and then, per templated variable it finds, generate 1 textbox. You list those textboxes, one per line, below the text and as soon as the contents in one textbox change, you update the text so that the user sees what this will look like.

Comment: So, you'd suggest to display the final text + a list of textboxes in a column beside the text, for example? I was thinking about putting them inside the text to make the link between the text the user in inserting and the template more clear. My fear is that the relation is too far apart this way.

Comment: I think that could be difficult for first-time users to grasp. Having the fields to fill in separate and clearly labelled is easier to understand IMHO.

Comment: OK, the point is that the placeholders will not be unique. Basically the user will place a sign in the document, like [], where he wants to insert a new piece of data, so I guess I need to keep a reference to that point in the document.